# I am new to pyspark. how do i do the following using pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe as below:

```
+-----------+--------------------+-----+
|      Index|                 lst|value|
+-----------+--------------------+-----+
|          1|[3,5,6,7]           |    1|
|          2|[2,6,8,1,2,3,4,5,7] |    5|
|          3|[5,6,7,5,4,3,2,3,1] |    2|
|          4|[8,7,6,4,3,2,3]     |    6|
+-----------+--------------------+-----+
```

I need to get the following:

```
+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------+
|      Index|                 lst|value|index_value|
+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------+
|          1|[3,5,6,7]           |    1|          5|
|          2|[2,6,8,1,2,3,4,5,7] |    5|          3|
|          3|[5,6,7,5,4,3,2,3,1] |    2|          7|
|          4|[8,7,6,4,3,2,3]     |    6|          3|
+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------+
```

I have used a udf to try and get the values, but was not able to successfully implement this. I know it is a very basic question, but I was able to do the required using pandas, but need to get the task done using pyspark. This example is a sample of the data that I have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the logic behind "index_value"  column ?

Comment: i have to use the elements from the value column as index for the lst column, and get the  index _value.
for example: 
lst = [1,2,3,4], value = 3 -> index_value = 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are essentially trying to get the value from `lst` based on the index value specified in `value` , you can achieve this by [getItem](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html) which is pyspark native to indexing `ArrayType`

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
Index|lst|value
1|3,5,6,7|1
2|2,6,8,1,2,3,4,5,7|5
3|5,6,7,5,4,3,2,3,1|2
4|8,7,6,4,3,2,3|6
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='|')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("lst", F.split(F.col("lst"), ",").cast("array<int>"))

sparkDF.show()

+-----+--------------------+-----+
|Index|                 lst|value|
+-----+--------------------+-----+
|    1|        [3, 5, 6, 7]|    1|
|    2|[2, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3...|    5|
|    3|[5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3...|    2|
|    4|[8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2...|    6|
+-----+--------------------+-----+

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- Index: long (nullable = true)
 |-- lst: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

#### GetItem

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("index_value", F.col("lst").getItem(F.col('value')))

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+-----+---------------------------+-----+-----------+
|Index|lst                        |value|index_value|
+-----+---------------------------+-----+-----------+
|1    |[3, 5, 6, 7]               |1    |5          |
|2    |[2, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]|5    |3          |
|3    |[5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]|2    |7          |
|4    |[8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3]      |6    |3          |
+-----+---------------------------+-----+-----------+
```